# How to get MTP device name

Tags: command-line, mtp

... I've tried search but it gives a tons of "how to connect MTP devices"

I just want to know how to get connected device name like (Nexus 10 or Galaxy S5), that I can see in Nautilus device list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this surprisingly tough. I have a Nexus 5 and KDE (using `libmtp`, I think) displays it as a Nexus 5. My first instinct was that KDE was simply looking at the hardware database. This maps vendor and product strings from USB devices to known names. Here's the problem:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 18d1:4ee1 Google Inc. Nexus 4
```

My Nexus 5 just got a downgrade! So KDE isn't getting it from there.

We can use `udevadm` to query devices. In this case we need to pass it a reference to the device. I'm going to use the bus/device numbers from above (they need to be `%03d` formatted, so 1 becomes 001, 20 becomes 020, etc):

```
$ udevadm info --name=/dev/bus/usb/002/011
...
E: ID_MODEL=Nexus_5
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Nexus\x205
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=Nexus 4
...
```

There's a lot of other crap in there but `ID_MODEL` seems to be what we want. If you need to further extract and process that, you could run it through `awk` (or another) to clean it up and replace the underscore:

```
$ ... | awk -F'=' '/ID_MODEL=/{gsub("_"," ");print $2}'
Nexus 5
```

Comment: as I'm running it from udev/rules script $env{ID_MODEL} works like a charm, thank you

Comment: Ah, even better.

Answer (score 8):

You can parse the output of `mtp-detect`.

First install `mtp-tools`:

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools
```

And run:

```
$ mtp-detect 2>/dev/null | grep Model:
    Model: Nexus 7 (2013) Wi-Fi
```

Comment: I've tried to avoid dependencies, but still thank you

Comment: I did have a look at `mtp-detect` but found it *seriously* slow. It took 40 seconds to complete here.

Comment: @Oli: With just my Nexus 7 plugged in, it's almost instantaneous, weird. But looking at udev is also a good choice :)